# Unexpected response after requesting home page spring + keycloak app

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, keycloak

After requesting the endpoint: `http://localhost:8083/microservice1/home`, once the *client credentials flow* chapter implemented of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9O99l4gjAc), I get the following answer:

```
Login ith OAuth 2.0
```

instead of the expected one [from here](https://github.com/onepseudoxy/spring-security-oauth2-keycloak-demo)
I tried to debug via Intellij, and run the request, but I don't know why It doesn't stop in breakpoints